# How To Get time for Different row

Tags: android

I create one application ,in which message are send from web service. i store the response in list view. when the response save in list view its give  same time for each row  ,i want different time latest time,but older time does not change. please give me some idea.The code is

```
    public class WebMessageAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<WebMessageCore>{

        Context _Context;
        ArrayList<WebMessageCore> _WebMsgList;
        WebMessageCore _WebMsgCore;
        TextView _MsgContent;
        private LayoutInflater mInflater;
        ImageButton Arrow;
        GabrielApplication application;
        public WebMessageAdapter(Context context, int resource,
         ArrayList<WebMessageCore> contactList) {
            super(context, resource,  contactList);
            _Context = context;
            _WebMsgList = contactList;
            mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        }

        public int getCount() {
            return _WebMsgList.size();
        }

        public WebMessageCore getItem(int position) {
            return _WebMsgList.get(position);
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }


        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ViewHolder holder;
            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_row_view, null);
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                holder.txtName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
                holder.txtmessage = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.meassage);
                holder.txtPhone = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.phone);
                holder.txtdate=  (TextView ) convertView.findViewById(R.id.datetime);
               //holder.Arrow =  (ImageButton)convertView.findViewById(R.id.settingArrow);
                convertView.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }

            _WebMsgCore=_WebMsgList.get(position);
            holder.txtName.setText(_WebMsgCore.getName());
            holder.txtmessage.setText(_WebMsgCore.getMessage());
           holder.txtPhone.setText(_WebMsgCore.getMobileNo());
           Arrow.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    Intent newActivity =  new Intent(_Context, ContactInfoActivity.class);
                    _Context.startActivity(newActivity);
            /*      
            Intent intent = new Intent(_Context, ContactInfoActivity.class);
                    GabrielUtil.replaceContentView(application.getGroupContext(),
                            GBConstants.contact_info, intent);*/
                }
            });

           String currentDateTimeString = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(new Date());
           holder.txtdate.setText(currentDateTimeString);
            return convertView;



        }


        static class ViewHolder {
            TextView txtName;
            TextView txtmessage;
            TextView txtPhone;
            TextView txtdate;
            ImageButton Arrow;
        }
    }'
```

Comment: post some code. If you are using custom adapter for your listview then atleast post its getView method.

Answer (score 0):

The actual problem at the line

```
String currentDateTimeString = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(new Date());
```

The above line gives the same date format such as May 9, 2012 4:36:12 PM. Because the `getView()` method executed within 650 miliseconds on my pc which gives same result. The time may vary dependending on pc's configuration. So you can try replacing the above line using

```
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd,yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS a");
        Date resultdate = new Date((new Date()).getTime());
        String currentDateTimeString = sdf.format(resultdate);
```